# Why is the 'null-namespace' expected for an xml element that was defined to 'have' a namespace in the schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

The following xml document and schema was boiled down from a much larger schema in which the problem occured first:

The xml document:

```
<f2b:Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:f2b="http://www.outerfoospace.com/schemas/foo2bar" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.outerfoospace.com/schemas/foo2bar f2b-0-0-0.xsd">
    <f2b:Bar>text</f2b:Bar>
</f2b:Foo>
```

The schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:f2b="http://www.outerfoospace.com/schemas/foo2bar" targetNamespace="http://www.outerfoospace.com/schemas/foo2bar">
    <xs:complexType name="T_Foo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Bar" xmlns="f2b"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Foo" type="f2b:T_Foo"/>
</xs:schema>
```

When I validate the document against the schema, I get an error message on the `<f2b:Bar>`-element saying that `<f2b:Bar>` is not expected. To make the document valid I have to put the `<Bar>`-element explicitly (!) into the 'null-namespace': `<Bar xmlns="">`.
I don't see why a null-namespaced element should be expected. The schema defines a namespace for all elements and for the `<Foo>`-element the `f2b`-namespace is indeed expected by the validator. But even if I explicitly set the namespace in the `<Bar>`-element definition like I did above, the validator still expects `xmlns=""` for the `Bar`-element.
I tried several variations of the schema and the document to find an answer with no luck - and I simply can't guess why the hell in this special case the null-namespace is expected.

Any hint appreciated ... ekke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the root `xs:schema` tag of your schema.

Longer answer: by default, only top-level "global" element declarations take on the target namespace of the schema. "Local" element declarations inside a complex type are in no namespace. You can override this for one particular local element using the `form` attribute on the `xs:element` tag, or globally for all elements using `elementFormDefault` on the `xs:schema`.